# Beginner question on how EOS is used in gambling

Tags: blockchains

Hey so there is this gambling site I use, which according to them uses the EOS blockchain to randomize the outcome. I'm trying to figure out if the games are rigged or not but can't get anywhere since I'm extremely new to crypto

I'll use an example from a game i played. The site says they use a provably fair system and give you

the block they produced which was # 330005472

Private hash: da187d823874c9ad63c718bdd1429314ea9e8c6c05b998e407293ac3c537af30

Private seed: 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

Public seed:13ab7be0484d91fd22f34a70b5506f918e74cfc8052e2276da62514dee51b3db

and the outcome of the game was a 3.25x multiplier.

I've tried using sha256 and a few other algorithms to check but the numbers never match and when i ask support they aren't to much help.

Could anyone tell me if they are cheating me or if it is legitimate, and if so how can I check?